# Create DBGrid columns at runtime with diffrent dataset (Table)

Tags: delphi

I want to create only certain columns on my "dbgrid" at run-time, and set them to
other table field(s) or same field .  How do you do that :
illustration:
I have 3 Tables :

```
Student(IdStudent, NameStudent ...) ,

Module(idModul,NameModule...),  

Notes(idNote,idStudent,idModul,Note).
```

I Want to insert All Notes in one Dbgrid and names of columns of DBgrid are names of Module Table. I have No idea?

Thanks.

Comment: example :  Module1 = column1,Module2 = column2,.......

Comment: What dataset do Module1 and Module2 belong to?

Comment: for example , Dbgrid contains N Columns, each colomn 'n' contains note of student (Module 'n'), So dataset of dbgird = Table 'Notes' but in 'Notes' table there is one field but Dbgrid contains N Columns (N modules) , how I link N columns with one field,÷I think that you understand the problem

Comment: You cannot do this with a dbgrid; dbgrids have only one datasource and a datasource has only one dataset.  If you are using an SQL compliant database you should look into a join and/or crosstab to return a single dataset. (I think this is what MartynA is talking about)  Or create a clientdataset at run-time and build it with the columns/data you want if you want data-aware.  I would look into using a stringgrid, listview or treeview and build the whole thing by hand.

Comment: @TDC:  I don't know whether it's what the OP wants, but I think your comments would make a good answer.  Why not post it as one?

Comment: Im not sure what the op wants but maybe lookup field(s) is the answer...

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do this with a dbgrid; dbgrids have only one datasource and a datasource has only one dataset. If you are using an SQL compliant database you should look into a join and/or crosstab to return a single dataset. (I think this is what MartynA is talking about) Or create a clientdataset at run-time and build it with the columns/data you want if you want data-aware. I would look into using a stringgrid, listview or treeview and build the whole thing by hand.